# Strict partition an RDD into multiple RDDs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an rdd with `n` partitions and I would like to split this rdd into `k` rdds in such a way that

```
rdd = rdd_1.union(rdd_2).union(rdd_3)...union(rdd_k)
```

So for example if `n=10` and `k=2` I would like to end up with 2 rdds where rdd1 is composed of 5 partitions and rdd2 is composed of the other 5 partitions.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Spark?

Comment: Proving more info on what you are trying to achieve might get you a more helpful answer. E.g. if you want to balance you partition sizes, you can use `repartition`. I cannot see how having an RDD per partition would server any purpose unless you also had you own partitioner. Also note, that there are many functions that can make use of the partition index so you can just `return` for invalid partitions. Last but not least, using `groupBy` could also be applicable if your partitions have a logical split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```scala
val rdd: RDD[T] = ???
val k: Integer = ???
val n = rdd.partitions.size

val rdds = (0 until n) // Create Seq of partitions numbers
  .grouped(n / k)  // group it into fixed sized buckets
  .map(idxs => (idxs.head, idxs.last)) // Take the first and the last idx
  .map {
    case(min, max) => rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
      // If partition in [min, max] range keep its iterator
      // otherwise return empty-one
      (i, iter) => if (i >= min & i <= max) iter else Iterator()
    )
  }
```

If input `RDD` has complex dependencies you should cache it before applying this.

Comment: Did you forget 'parallelize'? so far it only operates on Seq

Comment: @tribbloid I did not. The only RDD here is the input one (`rdd`). There is no place for `parallelize` here.